# iOS grid UI control

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard

In XCode Swift Storyboard with auto layout enabled I need to put a row of buttons (let it be 6 buttons) filling screen by width. The buttons must be of the same width, keeping aspect ration the same (so row height will change when screen width changes).

I think that I need to use an UI control like GridLayout in Android, but so far I can't find anything suitable in iOS.

Please advice.

Comment: If you're using iOS 9, you could look into stack views.

Comment: There's nothing in Interface Builder that allows you to do that automatically, that is, without having to position and set constraints for each your buttons yourself.  For iOS 9.0, `UIStackView` might be helpful for you, but until then (and possibly even still) I'd do it programmatically using `UICollectionView`.

Comment: @Patrick, probably I could accept it as an answer, will you please submit it?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in Interface Builder that allows you to do that automatically, that is, without having to position and set constraints for each your buttons yourself. For iOS 9.0, `UIStackView` might be helpful for you, but until then (and possibly even still) I'd do it programmatically using `UICollectionView`.